# Why to use types in python 3.5 +

Tags: python, types, python-3.5, python-3.6

I'm trying to understand why should I use types annotation in python. For exemple I can write function like:

```
def some_function(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

When I use it with int all gone good:

```
some_function(1, 2)  # return 3, type int
```

But when I run for exemple

```
some_function(1, 2.0) # return 3.0, type float
```

I have result without any notes that types are wrong. So what is the reason to use types annotation?

Comment: Type hints are not enforced at runtime. Run `mypy` on your project to get told you are using `some_function()` wrong.

Comment: IDE support....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type hints are there for *other tools* to check your code, they are not enforced at runtime. The goal is enable static analysis tools to detect invalid argument use.

Use an IDE like PyCharm, or the [commandline code checker `mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) to be told that `2.0` is not a valid argument type.

From the [Type Hinting PEP (484)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#rationale-and-goals):

> This PEP aims to provide a standard syntax for type annotations, opening up Python code to easier **static analysis and refactoring**, potential runtime type checking, and (perhaps, in some contexts) code generation utilizing type information.

Emphasis mine. Runtime type checking is left to third-party tools. Note that such runtime checks would come with a performance downside, your code will likely run slower if you were to check for types on every call.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just one addition, is it a good practice to use it in the code?

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov: absolutely! We use it at Facebook to make working in large projects easier and to reduce errors.

Comment: Quick question, are you supplying them via stubs or do you add them directly in the source files?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: we add them directly to *Python* source files. For C extensions, you are limited to stubs.

Answer (score 1):

As one can read in the PEP 484 [that introduces *type hints*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#rationale-and-goals):

> (...)
>
> This PEP aims to provide a standard syntax for type annotations,
>   opening up Python code to **easier static analysis and refactoring,
>   potential runtime type checking**, and (perhaps, in some contexts) **code
>   generation utilizing type information**.
>
> Of these goals, static analysis is the most important. This includes
>   support for **off-line type checkers such as mypy**, as well as providing
>   a standard notation that can be used by **IDEs for code completion** and
>   refactoring.

## IDE's (static analysis)

So the main use is in *static analysis*: your IDE can detect that something is wrong when you call a function and can provide a list of functions you can call on the result of function.

For instance if you write:

```
some_function(1,2).
```

your IDE can provide a list with `real` as a possible option so you can easily write:

```
some_function(1,2).real
```

and if you write:

```
some_function('foo',2).bar
```

It will hint that `'foo'` is not an acceptable parameter nor is `.bar` a good call on that object.

## Dynamic inspection

You can also use it for dynamic inspection with [`inspect.getfulargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect.getfull#inspect.getfullargspec) like:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(some_function).annotations
{'return': <class 'int'>, 'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'int'>}
```

Now we know that `some_function` returns an `int` and can be feeded two `int`s. This can be used for *arbitrary tests* (which are popular in Haskell): you simply feed the `some_function` random integers and looks that it always returns an `int` (and does not raises an exception for instance).